# TypeError : WebElement is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

In my Python script I am trying to scrape a Twitter page for up to 5 scrolls but my script is throwing a `TypeError` stating that `WebElements` is not iterable. Any way to solve this issue.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path_chromedriver = '/Users/SubrataMohanty/Desktop/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path_chromedriver)
base_url = u'https://twitter.com/search?q='
query = u'%40sachin_rt'
url = base_url + query

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

for _ in range(5) :
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)

tweets = browser.find_element_by_class_name('tweet-text')

for tweet in tweets :
    print(tweet.text)
```

Errors :

```
abhijeet-mohanty-2:Desktop SubrataMohanty$ python tweet_scraper.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet_scraper.py", line 23, in <module>
    for tweet in tweets :
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name()` returns a *single element*. You meant to find multiple elements by class name - use `find_elements_by_class_name()` method (note the `s`):

```
tweets = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')
#                        HERE^
for tweet in tweets :
    print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am currently in a stage of infancy when it comes to analyzing what I scrape and Python in general. What would you suggest to make a significant improvement?

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty practice and practice, of course. Look through the popular StackOverflow questions in web-scraping, selenium and python - this is also a good way to have a sense of common issues in these fields. Thanks.